# OTG support in Android Smartphones

Tags: usb-on-the-go

It seems that Samsung are phasing out OTG support in their latest devices, i.e. the S6 no longer has OTG support.

Is this a general trend across smartphone manufacturers? Also, I cannot see the reason for it, it makes the devices less flexible in how they can be used. Is there a downside to having an Android device support OTG that I may have missed?

Comment: if the s6 had otg support in previous/older firmware version, then it still is capable of otg support, samsung has a habit of neutralizing previously functioning aspects of hardware by omitting/disabling support at the level of the kernel. likely you can override that by correcting and compiling/installing your own custom kernel.

Answer (score 0):

"OTG support in Android Smartphones

the correct term is:

USB host support

can be easily detected if supported or not, connecting usb mouse to your smartphone via OTG cable.

If mouse is powered up and red laser is on, so supported.

The other way to detect if USB host mode is supported, is to install and run
USB OTG Checker app

Some claim USB Host Mode can be hidden and to enable it you should edit xml permissions configuration file